# Separate array of points into multiple arrays of points if they are far apart

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, noise, procedural-generation

I hope I am clear here, I will try to add images to help people understand my problem. I have a very simple Perlin noise lake generator:

[image: Perlin noise lake generator]

that outputs a lake as an array of points:

```js
[
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  ...
]
```

Using a simple tracer to generate a polygon from those points. It works very well and I was happy with it until I thought of an issue that might happen and then found the issue actually did happen. When you have two separate lakes in one chunk (like this)

[image: two separate lakes in one chunk]

the polygon tracer fails to create a valid polygon. I believe the solution is to go beforehand and separate points into groups of points, I looked up how to do this but all I found was an algorithm that needed to know how many groups there was supposed to be before it could work (which I do not know). I am completely stumped and would like some advice as to where to start with this. I don't need a full code answer (I can implement it myself), but a concept would be nice.

I will still be looking around and trying things while I wait for answers although I doubt with my knowledge that I will be able to find anything useful. Oh, and my polygon tracer uses marching squares if that is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [Clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). And since you say that you don't know the number of clusters beforehand, I would recommend the [Mean Shift algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that.